# Can't find ⌃ symbol in keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I'm working in xcode and under editor>estructure there is a "re-indent" feature with this shortcut: ⌃l

It sound really stupid, but I just moved from windows and for my life's sale I cannot figure out what key ⌃ is.

What key is the ⌃ key and where it's located on the keyboard?

Answer (score 49):

The following’s a list of the symbols in macOS and their symbols.

⎋   Escape

⇥   Tab Right

⇤   Tab Left

⇪   Caps Lock

⇧   Shift

⌃   Control

⌥   Option

⌘   Command

⏎   Enter

↩   Return

⌫   Delete

⌦   Forward Delete

↖   Home

↘   End

⇞   Page Up

⇟   Page Down

↑   Up Arrow

↓   Down Arrow

←   Left Arrow

→   Right Arrow

⏏   Eject

Comment: what is "Tab back" ?

Comment: Tab back = Shift+Tab

Answer (score 13):

^ is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> modifier key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

How to type the modifier key glyphs on MacOs:

1. "control+command+space" in any application
2. type "up arrowhead" to find: `⌃` (control)
3. type "option" to find: `⌥` (option / alt)
4. type "place of interest" to find: `⌘` (command / super)

Comment: How would the OP know that ^ is up arrowhead? Alll they know is that they see a ^ character

Comment: They would know when they read my answer to this question.

Comment: Or they would know if they copied and pasted `⌃` into google.

Comment: No your answer says type. "up arrowhead"