# What key does this ⇥ symbol represent in Apple help docs?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, bluetooth

Please help figuring out what this <kbd>⇥</kbd> key modifier refers to, in Apple's instructions in iPhone 6s settings below as shown in Settings app → Accessibility → Keyboards → Full Keyboard Access.

E.g., What key combo do I press on Apple bluetooth keyboard to invoke Notification Centre? I've tried <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+ <kbd>N</kbd> but to no avail. The keyboard *is* properly paired with the iPhone, and I can type text or navigate with the arrow keys.

[image: iPhone Full Keyboard Access preference under Settings app]

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, it only appears to be on US keyboards that the symbols are not present. All the International keyboards I've seen mainly use the icons, though it's a tad hit & miss. My UK keyboard has icons for Tab, CapsLock & Shift, then just the text 'control' then symbols **and** text for 'alt' [not opt, it says alt] & 'cmd'.

Comment: tbh, I thought it was pretty much universal. I've an old mechanical 'PC' keyboard here that must be at least 25 years old & that has the exact same symbol for tab, with no additional text.

Comment: What fun! Being from Android/PC world, I bashed my keyboard and googled for like half an hour before resorting to post here :) Why have `Tab` engraved on the keyboard and `⇥` in the docs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>⇥</kbd> symbol refers to the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on the keyboard.

A full list of keys and corresponding symbols as used in macOS can be found here:

- [Can't find ⌃ symbol in keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123568/cant-find-symbol-in-keyboard)